# Create table failed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have designed the schema and generated the create SQL below using the MySQLWorkbench.

This query through this error: Can't create table 'museum.statue_details'. Could someone please tell me what seems to be the problem and how to solve it? Thanks.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
    SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `museum` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
    USE `museum` ;

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`collection`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`collection` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`collection` (
      `collection_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `current_contact_person` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`collection_id`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`country`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`country` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`country` (
      `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `country_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`epoch`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`epoch` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`epoch` (
      `epoch_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `epoch_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`epoch_id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`artefact`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`artefact` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`artefact` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `collection_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `epoch_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      `year` DATE NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`, `collection_id`, `country_id`, `epoch_id`),
      INDEX `collection_id_idx` (`collection_id` ASC),
      INDEX `country_id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
      INDEX `epoch_id_idx` (`epoch_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `collection_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`collection` (`collection_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `country_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`country` (`country_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `epoch_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`epoch_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`epoch` (`epoch_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`painting_details`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`painting_details` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`painting_details` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `material` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `style` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`statue_details`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`statue_details` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`statue_details` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `material` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `height` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
      `weight` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
      `style` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`relic_details`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`relic_details` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`relic_details` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `material` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `usage` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`owner`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`owner` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`owner` (
      `owner_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `owner_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`owner_id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`other_artefact`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`other_artefact` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`other_artefact` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `artifact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`borrowed_artefact`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`borrowed_artefact` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`borrowed_artefact` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `owner_id` INT NULL,
      `collection_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `date_borrowed` DATE NULL,
      `date_returned` DATE NULL,
      INDEX `owner_id_idx` (`owner_id` ASC),
      INDEX `artifact_id_idx` (`artefact_id` ASC),
      INDEX `collection_id_idx` (`collection_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `owner_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`owner` (`owner_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `collection_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`collection` (`collection_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`permenent_artefact`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`permenent_artefact` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`permenent_artefact` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
      `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `date_acquired` DATE NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artefact_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`creator`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`creator` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`creator` (
      `creator_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `country_id` INT NULL COMMENT 'Country of origin',
      `epoch_id` INT NULL,
      `creator_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'The creator name is unique',
      `creator_dob` DATE NULL COMMENT 'Date of birth',
      `creator_dod` DATE NULL COMMENT 'Date of died',
      `main_style` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`creator_id`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `creator_name_UNIQUE` (`creator_name` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `country_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`country` (`country_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `epoch_id`
        FOREIGN KEY ()
        REFERENCES `museum`.`epoch` ()
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`created_artefact`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`created_artefact` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`created_artefact` (
      `artefact_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `creator_id` INT NULL,
      INDEX `creator_id_idx` (`creator_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `creator_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`creator_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`creator` (`creator_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`exhibition`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`exhibition` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`exhibition` (
      `exhibition_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `country_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
      `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      `end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`exhibition_id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `museum`.`artifact_displayed_during_exhibition`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `museum`.`artifact_displayed_during_exhibition` ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `museum`.`artifact_displayed_during_exhibition` (
      `exhibition_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `artefact_id` INT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`exhibition_id`),
      INDEX `artifact_id_idx` (`artefact_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `exhibition_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`exhibition_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`exhibition` (`exhibition_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
      CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
        REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;


    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Please paste the entire error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many constraints with the same name,change them or let mysql name them.

```
CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
```

this repeats everywhere.There are others.
Also in museum.creator you have missing columns:

```
 CONSTRAINT `epoch_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `museum`.`epoch` ()
```

You probably want `epoch_id` in between.All those fixed, it runs on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

you should give other name of your foreign keys like that:

insetead of

```
CONSTRAINT `artefact_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`)
REFERENCES `museum`.`artefact` (`artefact_id`)
```

do:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_mykey  --> give name as you like here to distinguich between others
FOREIGN KEY (`artefact_id`) 
REFERENCES `artefact` (`artefact_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

create table syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

I believe the issue lies with you declaring the table name with {name1}.{name2}.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collection` (
  `collection_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `current_contact_person` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`collection_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`

worked for me